# Nginx Downloads Slow From Browser - CURL/WGET Are Fine

Tags: nginx, http

I'm trying to serve large files (50-800mb) from a VPS using Nginx to host map files for a game server. Oddly, when downloading map files in game or in a browser I'm hitting only ~15mbps. When downloading via CURL or WGET on a separate machine (same network) I'm hitting 60mbps (my maximum). I have tried a variety of settings (sendfile on, max_chunk_size, directio, etc) without any change in behavior between them. Here is my configuration as it stands now:

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    access_log off;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_types application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    access_log off;
    root /var/www/home;
    index index.html;

    location / {
    }

    location ^~ /kf2 {
        alias /var/www/kf2;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ^~ /img {
        alias /var/www/img;
    }
}
```

I currently have sendfile removed for testing, but having it enabled made no difference anyways. Running a download to localhost with WGET reaches speeds over 200mbps, so I don't think this is a disk I/O limitation. I'm at a loss here and can't explain the discrepancy between curl/wget and downloading via a browser. Any help is appreciated.